# Redirect a POST to non-action url

Tags: url, web-applications, struts2

How can I redirect a POST request sent to a struts action to another url which is not a struts action (and hence the redirect-action didn't seem to be helpful to me) with all the parameters.

say form1 is POSTed to action1.action with param 1

how can I redirect that request and pass param1  to the new url which is not a struts action?

Comment: It's better to use session object to store required parameters that's what doing messageStore interceptor in strtus to resolve this kind problem.

Comment: will this other URL will be outside the context of your application?

Answer (score 0):

Using annotations I'll do it this way, on your action class:

```
@Results({
    @Result(name = "input", location = "home.jsp"),
    @Result(name = "success", location = "http://www.url.com", type = "redirect", params={"param1", "value1", "param2", "value"})
})
```